# Open-source symmetric encryption software with own key management

Tags: open-source, gui, encryption

I'm looking for an open-source encryption software that uses one or more symmetric encryption algorithms like AES. It should also be possible to use a hash algorithm for data consistency.
I would also like a key generator and the possibility to use my own keys or any files as a key and be able to influence, in case of AES, the IV.
It should have a simple GUI.

I already looked into EncryptPad and similar products but they didn't give me enough choice in key generation/usage.
I also didn't find anything on Github that matches my prerequisites.

I probably could write a software like that but like all security related products this probably isn't wise.

I'm hoping that I'm addressing the right platform and I would be grateful for any recommendations of software or places to look for it.